# OmniAuth Facebook Implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, omniauth-facebook

I have the following Table Structure where a User has many Oauths.

```
create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :age
      t.string :gender

      t.timestamps


create_table :oauths do |t|
      t.string :provider
      t.string :provider_uid
      t.string :oauth_token
      t.datetime :oauth_expires_at
      t.text :meta
      t.integer :user_id

      t.timestamps
```

Since i will be allowing multiple login for the user using Facebook, twitter, foursquare. i want to separate out the oauths into a new table.

**User Model**

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.name = auth.info.name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.oauths.provider = auth.provider
      user.oauths.provider_uid = auth.uid
      user.oauths.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauths.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
      user.oauths.save!
    end
  end
```

I am stuck as to how i can query the provider and uid from the Oauths table to check if the user exists otherwise create a new record for that user.

Comment: Break the method down more. `first_or_initialize` isn't going to work. There's a great railscast that will help a lot: http://railscasts.com/episodes/236-omniauth-part-2. Be sure to check out Part 1 of that series too: http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1

Comment: @pdobb will check it out and get back here :D

Comment: @HarshaMV why do you have **oauth_token and oauth_expires_at** fields when you already have them in oauths table? You are unnecessarily repeating your fields. Why not have an oauth_id in your users table and have proper association like `oauth belongs_to :user`?

Comment: @Mandeep i was testing the app as i wasnt able to fetch the content from the oauths table. please ignore that :D

Comment: @HarshaMV no issues :D and btw i think what you can do is have an instance method for your user and if your associations are setup properly then inside that method you can check if there's already that association present or not, something like user.oauths will give you a collection of various oauths associated with that user from there you can check if that provider exists or not, if not then create one

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the `where` method inside of a `User` class method. You have to be explicit and call the `where` method in the correct model. You should have something like this:

```
# app/models/user.rb
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  oauth = Oauth.find_by(auth.slice(:provider, :uid))
  if oauth
    oauth.user
  else
    User.create(...)
  end
end
```

Note: I used `find_by(...)` instead of `where(...).first` since you are using Rails 4.